# How can I tick an Excel checkbox from VBA Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, checkbox

I have opened an Excel file via VBA Access and can read and write in the Excel Cells. How can I tick an Excel Ckeck Box?

My code:

```
Dim Excel_App  As Object
Dim strExcel As String
Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel_App.Visible = True
Excel_App.Workbooks.Open fready
With Excel_App
    .CheckBox3.Value = True 'This line is used in VBA Excel and I need in  Access
End With
```

Comment: The checkbox doesn't belong to the `Excel.Application` instance. It doesn't even belong to the `Workbook` instance you've opened (and discarded); first thing you'll need to know if you're looking for an ActiveX or Office-Forms control. You'll find ActiveX controls in the worksheet's `OleObjects` collection, and Office-Forms controls in the `Shapes` collection (you'll also find the shape for embedded ActiveX controls in there though).

Comment: You'll also need to know the name of that checkbox

Comment: Thanks, the CheckBox type is Office-Forms. I didn't find the code in the link. I tried  Shape.CheckBox3.Value = True out of Excel.Application instance but in says "object requird".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkboxes belong to a specific collection on a specific `Worksheet`. Which collection this is, depends on the type of control you're looking for.

Your code is written as if the checkbox belonged to the `Excel.Application` object - that can't work.

First you need to keep a reference to that `Workbook` object you're opening, so instead of this:

> ```
> Excel_App.Workbooks.Open fready
> ```

You need this:

```
Dim book As Object ' early-bound: As Excel.Workbook
Set book = Excel_App.Workbooks.Open(fready)
```

If you don't know which worksheet to find the checkbox on, you'll have to iterate the workbook's `Worksheets` collection:

```
Dim sheet As Object ' early-bound: As Excel.Worksheet
For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
    'todo
Next
```

#### Form Controls

So we're looking for a `CheckBox` *form control*. We'll find that in the sheet's `Shapes` collection, and we'll know we're looking at a *form control* when its `Type` is `msoFormControl`; we'll know that it's a checkbox control when its `FormControlType` property returns `xlCheckBox`:

```
Dim sheet As Object ' early-bound: As Excel.Worksheet
For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
    Dim shp As Object ' early-bound: As Excel.Shape
    For Each shp In sheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = 8 ' early-bound: msoFormControl
            If shp.FormControlType = 1 ' early-bound: xlCheckBox
                'todo
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

So now we know `shp` is a checkbox *form control*. The `Value` is accessible through the `ControlFormat` object/property, so you can set the value of a checkbox named `Check Box 1` (that's the default name) like this:

```
If shp.Name = "Check Box 1" Then
    shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 'checked
End If
```

Of course if you already know which specific sheet you're looking for, there's no need to iterate them all.

#### ActiveX Controls

If the control is an ActiveX control, it's a whole different story; you'll find it in the `OLEObjects` collection instead, which contains `OLEObject` instances, which have an `Object` property that returns the `MSForms.CheckBox` object; you can get the name of the checkbox from the `OLEObject.ShapeRange.Name`:

```
Dim ctrl As Object ' early-bound: As Excel.OLEObject
For Each ctrl In sheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(ctrl.Object) = "CheckBox" Then ' early-bound: If TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If ctrl.ShapeRange.Name = "CheckBox1" Then
            ctrl.Object.Value = True ' checked
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Note that the early-bound `TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox` check is MUCH more robust than the late-bound `TypeName` check. You need to reference the MSForms type library through *Tools > References* to use it (it's already referenced if your VBA project has any `UserForm` component, in which case early-bound code is a no-brainer).

Comment: superb explanation!

Comment: Mat's Mug, It works very well, Thank you very much for your great help.