# Button Visible property not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a pretty simple spreadsheet with a Command Button (form control, not ActiveX) directly on the sheet. I want to make it so that when the button is clicked once, it is either hidden or locked so that it can't be clicked again without reopening the sheet.

[image: Photo of button and name here.]

I've tried `btnNewMonth.Visible` and `btnNewMonth.Locked`, and neither of these work. I've checked for typos about 500 times, and I can't find any. Is there something else I could be doing wrong?

I've pasted my whole code in here, but the offending line is the last one. It throws

> Run-time Error 424: Object required.

```
Sub btnNewMonth_Click()

Dim lastmonth As Variant

Cells(1, 1) = DateAdd("m", 1, DateValue(Cells(1, 1)))
lastmonth = Range("D6:D9")
Range("C6:C9") = lastmonth
Range("D6:D9") = ""
Range("B17:G18") = ""
Range("B20:G21") = ""

btnNewMonth.Visible = False  'Run-time error 424: Object required

End Sub
```

Comment: show declaration of btnBewMonth please

Comment: @SMeaden there's no such declaration - that's pretty much what the problem is ;-)

Comment: Try `oWS.Buttons("btnNewMonth").Visible = False` where `oWS` is the Worksheet object this Button is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004133/1188513) if you need to locate ActiveX or Form Controls on a worksheet.

In this case, this should suffice:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item("btnNewMonth").Visible = False
```

I'd warmly recommend working against a specific `Worksheet` object instead of implicitly or explicitly working off `ActiveSheet` though. For example if you change the `(Name)` property of your worksheet to, say, `SummarySheet`, then you can do this:

```
SummarySheet.Shapes.Item("btnNewMonth").Visible = False
```