# Turn off calculations on one sheet with Checkbox clicked

Tags: vba, excel

> object required

error on the CheckBox9 value line in my code. I want to turn off calculations for a single sheet in Workbook while a user makes edits to the various sheets.

I can't seem to figure out where my error is. Thanks for your help

```
Sub StopCalc()

If CheckBox9.Value = True Then
   Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = False
    Else
     Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = True
   End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Is `CheckBox9` - ActiveX check box or Forms?

Comment: If your checkbox is a form control (which I recommend, if you don't actively need ActiveX capabilities), then your check should be `If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 9").ControlFormat.Value = 1`

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera no need for the `If` statement, both branches are assigning an opposite Boolean value. This can be a one-liner. e.g. assuming `.Value` is a `Boolean`: `Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 9").ControlFormat.Value`

Comment: @Mat'sMug ActiveX is boolean, Forms unfortunately aren't (I think, haven't really checked. I DO know that "checked" returns 1 instead of "True").

Comment: Then assign to a Boolean expression `= (ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 9").ControlFormat.Value = 1)`

Comment: @Mat'sMug That works fam. You forgot to reverse the boolean though.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the whole `If` statement with:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = Not (Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox9)
```

---

Confirm name of checkbox:

[image: chkname]

Comment: I am now getting an error that says this function is not supported with the object

Comment: are you sure the checkbox is called `CheckBox9` ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004133/1188513) if you need to locate ActiveX or Form Controls on a worksheet.

Get your checkbox from the `Shapes` collection of your worksheet, as was discussed in the comments thread above:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = _
    Not (ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 9").ControlFormat.Value)
```