# Dialog Sheet in Excel returns error when I try to save value of combobox on sheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a DialogSheet (not a userform, this is just the way the sheet was set up nearly 20 years ago) that I have added a combobox to. I am trying to save the value of that combobox to a cell on my sheet but it I get the following error:

> Run-time error '438' : Object doesn't support this property or method.

Here is the sub that causes the error:

```
Sub ModelNameSelection_Change()

Dim ModelName As String

     ModelName = DialogSheets("setup").ModelNameSelection.Value

     Worksheets("sheet1").Unprotect

     Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 10).Value = ModelName

     Worksheets("sheet1").Protect 

End Sub
```

The dialog sheet the combobox is on is called "setup" and the combobox has the name ModelNameSelection.

Is there a specific way to refer to the value in the drop down box?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: `DialogSheets("setup")` apparently doesn't have a `ModelNameSelection` public member. What type of control is the combobox? Is it ActiveX or "Forms Controls"?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - DialogSheets only use the Forms control I think.

Comment: Do you have any other comboboxes on your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line:

```
ModelName = DialogSheets("setup").ModelNameSelection.Value
```

with:

```
ModelName = DialogSheets("setup").DropDowns("ModelNameSelection").Value
```

EDIT: Oops I didn't see @Tim Williams comment which has the same answer

Comment: It's ok, comments aren't answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46004133/1188513) - this should get you started:

```
Dim sheet As Object ' As DialogSheet?
Set sheet = DialogSheets("setup")
Dim shp As Excel.Shape
For Each shp In sheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoFormControl Then
        If shp.FormControlType = XlFormControl.xlDropDown Then
            'todo
        End If
    End If
Next
```

In other words, you access controls through the sheet's `Shapes` collection. Since you know the exact name of the control, you can retrieve the shape by name instead of iterating them all:

```
Set shp = sheet.Shapes("ModelNameSelection")
Debug.Assert shp.FormControlType = XlFormControl.xlDropDown
```

And from there use its `ControlFormat` property to get the control's `Value`:

```
ModelName = shp.ControlFormat.Value
```

Comment: Or `sheet.DropDowns("ModelNameSelection").Value`

Comment: @TimWilliams meh... I'd rather go through the `Shapes` collection ...there's just too many ways to do the same thing in this API =)

Comment: I tried it both ways and it works both ways, but returns the index of the item selected. I'm not sure if the OP was looking for the index or the actual text of the selection, but out of curiosity I have been trying to get the text to no avail. Any thoughts?